Python изменение префикса интерактивной консоли
Как все знают, в интерактивной консоли Python перед новой командой написано
>>> 
# Пример
>>> if True:
...   pass

Можно ли изменить это на что-нибудь другое? Например
P: if True:
 |   pass

Желательно для bpython и с возможностью вставить вывод своей функции (например для указания текущей папки)

Мда, в приложении на Android нельзя редактировать вопрос. И всё на английском. Нафиг я его скачал?

Можно задать этот вопрос на Мете ;-)

Для bpython смогу разобраться только позже, в стандартной оболочке это можно сделать так:
import sys

sys.ps1 = 'P: '
sys.ps2 = ' | '

Можно использовать форматированные строки для вставки функции
import sys
import os

sys.ps1 = f'{os.getcwd()}: '

Читать: Статья, sys.ps1, sys.ps2

вопрос был про интерактивную консоль.

@strawdog ответ и относится к интерактивной консоли

Всё работает. Правда модуль sys не имеет атрибутов ps1 и ps2. Но их можно поставить через setattr и всё прекрасно
